# How to improve sharpness and white balance

Tags: portrait, canon-5d-mark-ii, fashion

5 years experience shooting street fashion photography. My photos appear too dark, grainy, and low quality overall in comparison to other work in my category. Any suggestions on aperture settings or post processing to capture crisp, vibrant, and bright photos. Here is a photo from my last shoot followed by how I want them to look. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I must say I like your photo better than the example. But I am answering with some tips.

Comment: As others have already said, lighting, but that wasn't the first thing that I noticed though. I noticed the composition first. You're too wide! get in there tight and don't waste the space in your frame.

Comment: After five years, that's what you are getting? My suggestion is to take a class or find an instructor. You need WAY more help than just a change in camera settings or post processing.

Answer (score 1):

**Lighting.**

The top photo is in open shade, so you get a fairly even light with soft shadows. The bottom one is in direct sun, giving much brighter highlights and stronger shadows. Look at the collarbone of the two models the transition from light to shadow around the collarbone in the top photo is gradual, and the difference between the brightest and darkest area isn't all that much. The opposite is true in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the two main factors...

### 1) Deept!

Why shooting against a flat wall? Shoot the same wall but in perspective! or do whatever trick you can thin, an alley, the 5th avenue, a forest. Anything but give depth to your image.

### 2) Shadows

Your image light is flat. Bounce a light on one side to give a litle light kik, or put a flash behind as a hair light, or use the sun as a backlight, or, if you follow tip one, and do not use a flat wall, the light also will be somehow diferent on one side than other.

---

The post processing is relative, You can think of increasing contrast and saturation, but that is a little too board.

---

I do not like the second image. Normally that sun position is one to avoid. To take a shoot like that just go to a sunny spot.

It is a lot better if you put the sun behind your model.